# Find min from list with numbers and strings

Tags: prolog

I have a list of cities defined this way

```
%city(name,latitude,longitude)
city(brussels,50.8462807,4.3547273).
city(tirana,41.33165,19.8318).
city(andorra,42.5075025,1.5218033).
city(vienna,48.2092062,16.3727778).
city(minsk,53.905117,27.5611845).
city(sarajevo,43.85643,18.41342).
city(sofia,42.6976246,23.3222924).
city(zagreb,45.8150053,15.9785014).
```

And the given predicates to calculate the distance between two cities

```
%  dist_cities(brussels,prague,D).
%  D = 716837.
dist_cities(C1,C2,Dist):-
    city(C1,Lat1,Lon1),
    city(C2,Lat2,Lon2),
    distance(Lat1,Lon1,Lat2,Lon2,Dist).

degrees2radians(Deg,Rad):-
    Rad is Deg*0.0174532925.

% distance(latitude_first_point,longitude_first_point,latitude_second_point,longitude_second_point,distance
% in meters)
distance(Lat1, Lon1, Lat2, Lon2, Dis2):-
    degrees2radians(Lat1,Psi1),
    degrees2radians(Lat2,Psi2),
    DifLat is Lat2-Lat1,
    DifLon is Lon2-Lon1,
    degrees2radians(DifLat,DeltaPsi),
    degrees2radians(DifLon,DeltaLambda),
    A is sin(DeltaPsi/2)*sin(DeltaPsi/2)+ cos(Psi1)*cos(Psi2)*sin(DeltaLambda/2)*sin(DeltaLambda/2),
    C is 2*atan2(sqrt(A),sqrt(1-A)),
    Dis1 is 6371000*C,
    Dis2 is round(Dis1).
```

What I'm trying to achieve now is, given a city, find the city with the shortest distance.

I've come up with this to collect all the cities and their respective distances to the starting point

```
visit(_, [], []).

visit(S, [H | T], [(H, D) | T1]):-
  dist_cities(S, H, D),
  visit(S, T, T1).
```

But I'm unsure how to output the city name and respective distance given this is my resulting list

```
?- visit(brussels, [minsk, zagreb, tirana], L).
L = [(minsk, 1603870),  (zagreb, 1023569),  (tirana, 1589189)] .
```

I know how to find the min from a list of numbers but I'm unsure here since the list is written as (CityName, Distance).

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an accumulator style recursion, unpacking the pair of values using pattern matching. If two cities are the same minimum distance, the choice points are in place so they can both be found. Starting with L:

```
closest(City, Distance) :-
    L = [(minsk, 1603870),  (zagreb, 1023569),  (tirana, 1589189)],
    % use first case as starting point
    L = [(TestCity, TestDistance)|Cities],
    % call accumulator recursive function, City and Distance unground.
    closest(Cities, City, Distance, TestCity, TestDistance).

% base case, set returned values to min found
closest([], City, Dist, City, Dist).
% case where new test case is min
closest([(NewCity, NewDist)|Cities], City, Distance, _, TestDist) :-
    NewDist is min(NewDist, TestDist),
    closest(Cities, City, Distance, NewCity, NewDist).
% case where old test case is min
closest([(_, NewDist)|Cities], City, Distance, TestCity, TestDist) :-    
    TestDist is min(NewDist, TestDist),
    closest(Cities, City, Distance, TestCity, TestDist).
```